# Using Ethereum as a ACID database?

Tags: database

I need a reliable ACID database with complex transactions. It is a hassle to do this in Java or other high level languages, especially if the database spans multiple systems and networks. For this purpose, I wanted to use the ACID features of smart contracts (if an error then the blockchain is rolled back) to implement my internal app (a one or two node private network).

Does this make sense? Will there be performance issues? I can wait a second or so before the response.

Answer (score 4):

> I can wait a second or so before the response.

This is a crucial requirement, because reading is way slower than with MySQL at al. What you need to do is to

- set up a private network
- learn about writing and reading data to/from smart contracts (what is possible, and what's not yet)
- create a private network
- make one node mine
- connect your applications through web3, hook web3 up into nodejs microservices or use
  https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj for java.

But be aware, this is not done in a week for Ethereum beginners.

Good Luck !

Comment: In terms of costs, is it a good idea to use ethereum as a DB ? I think It is too costly or not ?

Comment: If your application still works when writing one bit to the database costs $20, then this technology might be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, solidity is not ACID compliant. Particularly the isolation[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) part of ACID. For example, when running a for-loop that runs transactions or loops through values, if a secondary user runs the program at the same time and executes the same function, the loop will auto-increment to 0 since it's starting over. Solidity in now way should be used as a database and is not ACID compliant, although it is very durable and very consistent, it lacks isolation and atomicity to the fullest extent.